# Looking up a Hyperlink for use in custom view

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, hyperlink

This is for SharePoint Online.

I have a lookup list called COURSES, which contains the CourseName and CourseLink.  I also have a lookup list called ROLES, which contains organizational roles.  The relationship between the two lists is many-many, so I bridge them with list called ROLE-COURSE.  I then display the content of the ROLE-COURSE list in a nicely formatted page.  All works, except I cannot lookup the CourseLink field if it is type URL, so I've created a text version of it.  I can bring in the text version, but cannot get it to display as clickable URL in the page.  Ultimately I'd like to also cast the CourseName field in the page as clickable to the CourseLink as well.

I could always simply add a CourseLink field to the ROLE-COURSE table, but then users would have to enter something repeatedly that they should be able to lookup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As SharePoint does not support to have hyperlink column as lookup field, you might have to use some additional scripting to get the desired solution.

You may try following steps to get the desired output.

1. Create `CourseLink` column in **COURSE** list as `Single line of text`.
2. Update `Course` lookup column in **ROLE-COURSE** list as shown in following screenshot. i.e. `CourseLink` column is taken as an additional lookup field.
   [image]

Now with the help of following `Client-Side Rendering` script, we can modify the **ROLE-COURSE** list view.

Insert a `Script-Editor` web part in the **ROLE-COURSE** list view page and insert following script into it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    (function () 
     { 
        // jQuery library is required in this sample 
        // Fallback to loading jQuery from a CDN path if the local is unavailable 
        (window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"><\/script>')); 

        // Create object that have the context information about the field that we want to change it's output render  
        var lookupHyperlinkContext = {}; 
        lookupHyperlinkContext.Templates = {};  
        lookupHyperlinkContext.Templates.OnPostRender = hideFields; 
        lookupHyperlinkContext.Templates.Fields = { 
            // convert lookup field hyperlink from 'ItemLink' to 'CourseLink'
            'Course': {'View':function(ctx) {
                var url = ctx.CurrentItem.Course_x003a_CourseLink;
                return String.format('<a href="{0}">{1}</a>', url, ctx.CurrentItem.Course[0].lookupValue);
            }} 
        }; 

        SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(lookupHyperlinkContext); 

    })();  


    // logic to hide additional lookup column field
    function hideFields(ctx) 
    { 
        var cell = $("div [name='Course_x003a_CourseLink']").closest('th'); 
        var cellIndex = cell[0].cellIndex + 1; 

        $('td:nth-child(' + cellIndex + ')').hide(); 
        $('th:nth-child(' + cellIndex + ')').hide(); 
    }

 </script>
```

**Output**
Now you should be able to see `Course` values with hyperlink as `CourseLink`.

[image]

Comment: Very thorough answer - thanks for posting.  One problem I'd noticed was that I had the column names wrong - I'd been using what I'd thought was the internal name (by checking the field=___ portion of the link), but that was giving me %5F characters for any underscores in the column name.